# EKS cluster access - aws-auth : add groups in mapRoles

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, eks

i try to access an EKS cluster on AWS with AWS Account (same i use for the console)

steps i followed :

`aws configure` with info provided in the "Command line or programmatic access" (AWS Access Key Id/AWS Secret access key) + add the AWS session token in the credential file.

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --name XXXXXXX --region eu-west-1
```

in the ConfigMap : aws-auth file i added `- system:masters`  in the groups of my role
is it ok to add this here ?

```
mapRoles: |
    - groups:
      - system:bootstrappers
      - system:nodes
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXX:role/XXXXXXXX-group-role
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
    - groups:
      - eks-console-dashboard-full-access-group
      - system:masters    <<--- [[ is it ok to add this group here ?? ]]
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::MYACCOUNT:role/AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess_XXXXXXXX
      username: AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess_XXXXXXXX
```

then i try kubectl get svc : and i get :

```
E0207 16:37:31.292453   45292 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.sk1.eu-west-1.eks.amazonaws.com/api?timeout=32s": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

what does that error mean ? is it a rights problem ? a networking problem ? (security groups allows my ip)
thanks for your help

Comment: Timeout is always a security group issue, or perhaps your apiserver endpoint is in a Private VPC (the hostname will always look the same, but whether it resolves to a Public IP address is the difference). As for your `system:masters` question, yes, it should be fine although there's no reason to be in both groups since `system:masters` is, AFAIK, as high as it gets in k8s RBAC authorities

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  
my ip is allowed in All traffic, in the SG of : my ALB, my bastion on aws, and the EKS cluster,   and i stiil get this error :
E0208 13:16:08.468631     796 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.sk1.eu-west-1.eks.amazonaws.com/api?timeout=32s": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
Unable to connect to the server: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

there is no SG left?

Comment: i found what was missing : i also had to add my public ip adress in 
EKS/Clusters > Manage networking > cluster endpoint in « Public and private »  > advanced setting>  "Add/edit sources to public access endpoint",  we can add a CIDR block   and now it ok

Comment: I'm glad it was something simple, please [add and accept your own answer](https://serverfault.com/help/self-answer) so others will benefit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found what was missing :
i add my public ip adress in EKS/Clusters > Manage networking > cluster endpoint in « Public and private » > advanced setting> "Add/edit sources to public access endpoint", we can add a CIDR block
and now it is ok